# How do I view crash from iTunes Connect in Xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, crash-reports

I have an app that is running with React-Native that doesn't crash on `react-native run-ios`, neither when I run it on Xcode, but when I upload it to iTunes Connect, the build is refused because of a crash.
The problem is that I cannot see the crash on `Xcode > Window > Organizer > Crashes`, because I cannot make it crash with a device or a simulator.
Does somebody know how to import a crash that comes from iTunes Connect to Xcode ?

Here is my crash log :

```
{"app_name":"mdef","timestamp":"2017-12-11 11:40:02.33 -0800","app_version":"1.2.0","slice_uuid":"3ff1d45d-3b65-325e-8df9-5b0ccf7550b7","adam_id":1246228626,"build_version":"66","bundleID":"com.mdef.mymatchup","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.2 (15C114)","incident_id":"A6BCA3E0-DBB1-4E24-82F1-7B418F023CB0","name":"mdef"}
Incident Identifier: A6BCA3E0-DBB1-4E24-82F1-7B418F023CB0
CrashReporter Key:   972854c2d639e93f8277daa382921f72f9e8d379
Hardware Model:      xxx1
Process:             mdef [12142]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/07E05B5A-9B60-4A2E-BE1B-895E72344FC5/mdef.app/mdef
Identifier:          com.mdef.mymatchup
Version:             66 (1.2.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.mdef.mymatchup [5622]


Date/Time:           2017-12-11 11:40:02.1820 -0800
Launch Time:         2017-12-11 11:40:01.1784 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2 (15C114)
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  1

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x185cbe364 0x184f04528 0x185cbe2ac 0x104a8ff40 0x104a8dc04 0x185cc5cd0 0x185ba456c 0x185ba901c 0x104aa10b8 0x104ae0dd8 0x104ae0b38 0x18563aa54 0x18563aa14 0x18564496c 0x1856452fc 0x185645d20 0x18564e03c 0x1858e2f1c 0x1858e2b6c)
```

Comment: too little info, what is the crash? if it is not passing to the store there is no way to import anything

Comment: Yes excuse me, I edited my post with the crash log.

Comment: @NoémieKerroux kindly check out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved ! I have fixed my problem by downgrading React-Native from 0.51.0 to 0.49.5, and I have no more crashes.

Answer (score 2):

First of all in organiser crash logs will imported automatically if there will be any crash occurs on live app version.

Here you mentioned that your uploaded binary rejected due to crash issue. So they have provided you crash logs. Now that crash logs will not be imported into Xcode because App is not live yet.

So my suggestion is to resolve crash issue using this crash logs & lets get approval of application & make it live on app store. So after that if any user gets crash issue you will get list of it on Xcode -> Organiser.

**Edit :**

- If you are not able to find out or detect the crash log than you should ask apple review team to provide more details regarding that crash issue
- They can provide device & OS details to regenerate the crash also they can provide you steps to reproduce the crash.
- If everything works than you should try & re upload new binary. You will surely get approval after this ways

For more better crash issues with detailed analysis you can use this crashlytics tool : https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics

Hope it will help you.

Thanks...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but the thing is I don't get how to read the crash log, it can't see in it why it crashed. I works fine on devices when built with Xcode. It just says abort() called but nothing more, I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: @NoémieKerroux i understand your issue. I got it quite few times. Kindly check edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will ask it to the apple review team.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic tools like fabric [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/summary). whenever your app crashes on any device, Crashlytics will give you a detailed report about the crash on the dashboard with exact line number and details of the user's device.

[Read this](https://medium.com/delivery-com-engineering/add-crashlytics-to-your-react-native-ios-app-69a983a9062a) blog written by [Bruno Barbieri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1236940/brunobar79) about integrating Crashlytics in your react native app.

Or you can see crash manually from Xcode organizer.
[read this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html) to know more about checking crash reports from Xcode.